# Как убрать знаки препинания и спецсимволы из текста?

Tags: java, текст

Работаю с текстами - считываю их и вывожу слова. Надо что бы слова были чистые, то есть без всяких знаков и тому подобного. Есть метод который убирает знаки, но не все. Чаще всего попадаются `: - ! ? -- " <<`. Помогите, пожалуйста, улучшить метод.

```
private void ProcessLine(String line) {
    String[] words = line.split("[\\s+.,\";-]");
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.equals("")) continue;
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        Integer count = freqDictionary.get(word);
        if (count == null)
            count = 0;
        count++;
        freqDictionary.put(word, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Удалить все служебные символы несложно, нужно пойти от обратного и определить диапазон разрешенных символов.`s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]", "")`, но ваш код расходится с текстом вашего вопроса. Вы ищете кол-во уникальных слов в строке?

Comment: А если `какое-то` слово должно содержать дефис?

Answer (score 2):

Можно подойти с другой стороны, и получать регулярным выражением сами слова:

```
public Map<String, Long> wordsCount( String line ) {
    // \w - класс word characters, по-умолчанию [a-zA-Z_0-9], но с флагом
    //   Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS включает так же все прочие буквы
    Pattern word = Pattern.compile( "\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS );
    Matcher matcher = word.matcher( line );

    Map<String, Long> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
    while ( matcher.find() ) {
        String word = matcher.group().toLowerCase();
        wordCount.merge( word, 1L, Long::sum );
    }


    return wordCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример того, как можно убрать спецсимволы из строки, чтобы потом можно было разбить ее на слова и посчитать кол-во вхождений.

```
String line = "Однажды был случай в далеком Макао:" +
           "Макака коалу в какао макала," +
           "Коала какао лениво лакала," +
           "Макака макала, коала икала.";

line = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]", " ");
System.out.println(line.split("\\s+").length);
// 19
```

**PS:** На самом деле дефис может являться частью слова, не знаю оговорено ли это вашим заданием.